# isn&#39;t this wikipedia Definite integrals involving rational or irrational expression wrong!?

Tags: integration

[image: photo]

isn't this wikipedia Definite integrals involving rational or irrational expression wrong!?

According to my calculations:
$\sin[\frac{(m+1)\pi}{n}]$ while in wiki it is 
$\sin[\frac{(m+1)}{n}]$

seems $\pi$ missed.

here is result of my work:

$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^m \, dx}{({x^n+a^n)}^r}=\frac{(-1)^{r-1}\pi a^{m+1-nr}\Gamma [(m+1)/n]}{n\sin[\pi (m+1)/n](r-1)!\Gamma[(m+1)/n-r+1]} \ \ , 0<m+1<nr$

ref:[List of definite integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_definite_integrals)

**Remark:**
@icurays1 in your link there is another wrong  $\Gamma [\frac {(m+1)}{(n-p+1)}]$ while it could be $\Gamma [(\frac {m+1}{n})-p+1]$
[image: photo]

Comment: @icurays1 i check several times it seems to me $\pi$ is missed.

Comment: What would Jesus Wolfram Alpha say?

Comment: @L. F. my work is same but just there is a $\pi$ that i mention.

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment - @neo you might be correct, I've found [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ41/integ41.html) which agrees with you.  Someone should verify with a published table though, for instance Gradshteyn-Ryzhik

Comment: Alternately, if @neo is willing to share their work, we could check their work and then someone can edit the wiki.

Comment: Well, **something** is wrong on that Wikipedia page. The second expression is a special case of the one you listed above, but the right hand sides do not agree.

Comment: @nbubis Most of the time Jesus Wolfram Alpha says "calculation too complicated...give me your money and I will do it!" ;-)

Comment: @icurays1 ok thanks for the hyperlink its look like my work

Comment: @Neo: Have you proved this formula?

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal yes i just ask to make sure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is definitely wrong.  Take $a=1, m=0, n=2, r=1$.  Then it reads
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2 \sin(1/2)}$$
which is false.  The correct value is $\pi/2$, which agrees with your proposed $\sin\left[\frac{(m+1)\pi}{n}\right]$.

Taking the sine of a rational number is definitely a red flag.

Comment: ok so wikipedia equation must be modified